How do I apply the shooting method to a BVP with Robin's mixed condition in $t_0$ and $T$?
I have this BVP (Robin-Robin) and I don't know how to transform it to PVI and then give algebraic conditions for solutions:
\begin{array}{lll}
-x''(t)+p(t)x'(t)+q(t)x(t) = -r(t),~t\in [t_0,T] \\
,x'(t_0) + \alpha x(t_0) = a\\
,x'(T) + \beta x(T) = b
\end{array}
